# equivalent polynomial equations with yet different solutions?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I encountered a strange situation that I cannot explain. I am solving this simple equation for $g$:

\begin{equation}
    g= \frac{p}{a-\lambda-g}+\frac{1-p}{-\lambda-g}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a fixed value, $0\leq p \leq 1$ and $\lambda$ $\in \mathbb{C}$ unspecified.

If $a=0$ the equation simply is quadratic:
\begin{equation}
g=\frac{1}{-\lambda -g}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies -g^2-g\lambda-1=0
\end{equation}
and the solution simply is:
$$g_{\pm}\to \frac{1}{2} \left(-\lambda \pm\sqrt{\lambda ^2-4}\right)$$
However if I solve for general $a$, then the equation becomes a polynomial of order $3$ (i.e $Ag^3+Bg^2+Cg+D=0$). I get three solutions for $g\in \mathbb{C}$. And here is the problem: when I put $a=0$ $\textit{after}$ solving this polynomial I do not recover my $g_{\pm}$ (I get very lengthy solutions on mathematica, which is why I am not putting them here).

The equations are equivalent when $a=0$. Why are the solutions not equivalent when $a=0$?

So strange. If someone could explain why it does not hold and shed some light on this question it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Rewriting the first equation, we get:
$$
a g^{2}+a g \lambda-g^{3}-2 g^{2} \lambda-g \lambda^{2}-p a+a-g-\lambda=0
$$
Setting $a=0$ we obtain:
$$
\implies -g^{3}-2 g^{2} \lambda-g \lambda^{2}-g -\lambda=0
$$
Which is not the same quadratic equation as above. Why is that so?

Comment: Have you get this here

Comment: $$a{g}^{2}+ag\lambda-{g}^{3}-2\,{g}^{2}\lambda-g{\lambda}^{2}-pa+a-g-
\lambda
$$

Comment: Yes ! However setting $a=0$ I do not manage to recover the quadratic equation. Where would be my mistake/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: The equation you get setting $a=0$ *is not* the original quadratic but *contains* the original quadratic. If you take
$$-g^2-g\lambda-1=0$$
and multiply it by $(g+\lambda)$, you recover
$$-g^3-2g^2\lambda-g\lambda^2-g-\lambda=0.$$

**Longer answer**: It's easy to introduce spurious roots when manipulating rational equations to cast them into polynomial shape. To obtain a quadratic, you first multiply your equation
$$g=\frac{1}{-\lambda-g}$$
by a factor of $(-\lambda-g)$. However, in the cubic case, your equation is
$$g=\frac{p}{a-\lambda-g}+\frac{1-p}{-\lambda-g},$$ so you multiply the equation by $(-\lambda-g)$ *and* by $(a-\lambda-g)$ to obtain a cubic. Your intuition is right, if we set $a=0$ we ought to recover the roots of the quadratic. However, by setting $a=0$ you still recover a third degree polynomial because you have, in practice, multiplied the equation $$g=\frac{1}{-\lambda-g}$$ by $(-\lambda-g)$ and by $(0-\lambda-g)$, which is to say by $(-\lambda-g)$ twice. The additional multiplication introduces the $g=-\lambda$ root (check you get this one numerically); as soon as you spot this, you recover the desired quadratic.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I does help a lot indeed, thank you. I do (finally) recover the roots of the quadratic and the extra $g=-\lambda$ root. However this is only true for small $\lambda$, when $\lambda$ is out of $(-1,1)$ the result diverges from the true solutions... Any idea why this happens? (last question!)

Comment: When I solve the cubic equations for general $a$ I get three solutions: $g_1, g_2,g_3$. When I put $a=0$, what should happen is that $g_1=-\lambda$, $g_2=g_+$ and $g_3=g_-$. However it only true for small $\lambda$: The taylor series of $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are the same as $-\lambda, g_+,g_-$ but only up to the first term.

Comment: Which value of $p$ are you using? I just performed a quick numerical check, solving [the quadratic][1] and [the cubic][2] with the same parameters. Using a small value of $a$, two of the roots converge to the roots of the quadratic, and the last root converges to $z=-\lambda$.


  [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20z%20%3D%20p%2F(-l-z)%20%2B%20(1-p)%2F(-l-z)%20for%20p%20%3D%201%2F2%20for%20l%20%3D%203
  [2]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20z%20%3D%20p%2F(a-l-z)%20%2B%20(1-p)%2F(-l-z)%20for%20p%20%3D%201%2F2%20for%20a%20%3D%201%2F1%20for%20l%20%3D%203